# Blocking error Laravel Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: laravel

I have two tables, a table "métier" and a table "tâche" with one to many connection, a "métier" has several "tâche". In my form "ajouter tâches" I would like to have a combobox from which I choose the "métier" associated with the "tâche". These are my tables and how I proceeded and the error I got.

**Model1**

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tache extends Model
{
public function metier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Metier::class);
}

public function tarificationtache()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tarificationtache::class);
}


}
```

**Model2**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class metier extends Model
{
 public function metier()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tache::class);
}
}
```

**Controller1**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Tache;
use App\Metier;
class TacheController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $Listtache=tache::all();
    return view('tache.index',['tache'=>$Listtache]);


}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{

    //$metiers = Costcenter::lists('libelle_metier', 'id');
    $metiers = Metier::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('tache.create')-> with('metiers');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tache = new Tache();
    $tache ->libelle_tache =$request->input('libelle_tache');
    $tache ->Tarif =$request->input('Tarif');
    $tache ->metier_id =$request->input('metier_id');
    $tache->save();
    return redirect('tache');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $tache=Tache::find($id);
    return view('tache.edit',['libelle_tache'=>$metier],
['Tarif'=>$tache]);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $tache =Tache::find($id);
    $tache->delete();

    return redirect('tache');
}
}
```

**Controller2**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Metier;

class MetierController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $Listmetier=metier::all();
    return view('metier.index',['metier'=>$Listmetier]);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('metier.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $metier = new Metier();
    $metier ->libelle_metier =$request->input('libelle_metier');
    $metier->save();
    return redirect('metier');

}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(metier $id)
{
    return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $metier=Metier::find($id);
    return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $metier=Metier::find($id);
    return view('metier.edit',['libelle_metier'=>$metier]);
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $metier =Metier::find($id);
    $metier->delete();

    return redirect('metier');
}
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@section('content')
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <ul>
    @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
     <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action=" {{url ('tache')  }}" method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Libelle Tache</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="libelle_tache" class="form-
control"value="{{old('libelle_tache')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Tarif</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="Tarif" class="form-
control"value="{{old('tarif')}}">
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="metier">metier</label>
                <select name="metier_id" id="metier">

                        @foreach($metiers as $metier)

                         <option value="{{$metiers}}">
                            {{$metiers->libelle_metier}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach




                </select>
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" 
 class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you do not pass `$metiers` to the view. So, change the code to:

```
return view('tache.create')->with('metiers', $metiers);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works now but i got a new error  "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":3,"libelle_metier":"metier3","created_at":"2018-02-13 14:26:42","updated_at":"20

Comment: @IT2704 please create a new question and attach all related data and code.